# Use vscode with debug mode with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, multiprocessing

When I run vscode with debug mode using multiprocessing I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: already started
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on: https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1443

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', True)
```